# Remove items from a list by equal quantity in JS

Tags: javascript

```
let a = [1, 1, 1, 2];
let b = [{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1}];

// [true, true, false, true, true, false, false]
result = [{id: 1}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]
```

In other words, if there are 3 instances of the number 1 in list 'a' and there are 4 instances of the number 1 in list 'b', then 3 instances will be excluded, and so on.

What would be a way to solve this? I've tried several codes and couldn't succeed.

Comment: You need to make an attempt and show your code. See [ask].

Comment: First run a loop through a and prepare one occurance based json.. ex: { 1 : 3, 2: 1}.. then run through second list to make comparisons against the json object and keep a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `b`. If the `id` value is in `a`, remove that element from `a`; otherwise, include that element in the result.

```js
let a = [1, 1, 1, 2];
let b = [{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 1}];

let c = b.filter(el => {
  let a_index = a.indexOf(el.id);
  if (a_index != -1) {
    a.splice(a_index, 1);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(c);
```